# jQuery Conflict or

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i'm using [sticky.js](http://stickyjs.com) plugin and now i wanna use it when width greater that 768px so i use :

```
jQuery(function($){
    var min_width = parseInt( $('body').css('min-width'), 10 );

    if ( min_width > 768 ) {
        $("#header").sticky({
            className : 'sticky-header' ,
            topSpacing : -45
        });
    }
});
```

but it dosn't work for me . i think that there is jQuery conflict because codes looks correct .
what should i do ?

[live demo](http://bloodmyst.com)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var min_width = $(window).width();
```

instead of

```
var min_width = parseInt( $('body').css('min-width'), 10 );
```

min-width will give you only the min-width you defined in you css file, not the actual size of the body / window.

Comment: thanks but can you reply all codes that i should to replace ? i'm beginner in jquery

Comment: I've updated the answer to make clear what you should replace.

Comment: bastian , i updated codes but still no result on bloodmyst.com

Comment: Just tried it in firefox and it's working, the header is sticky (keeps its position on scrolling).